# Windows Bash (WSL) - sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After following [this tutroial](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/upgrade-bash-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts) I get the following error when trying to run the commands as user or even sudo:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

The comments from [Lurdan](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/upgrade-bash-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts#post-2819669254) in this article state that you need to run

```
sudo -S <YOUR_COMMAND>
chmod 0666 /dev/tty
```

`chmod` doesn't work but `sudo -S` does, but surely there's another fix?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So silly, after looking further down I see a solution from [Beorat](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/upgrade-bash-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts/#post-2822845588):

> To avoid the sudo tty issue and others, run these commands just before running do-release-upgrade:

```
sudo -S apt-mark hold sudo
sudo -S apt-mark hold procps
sudo -S apt-mark hold strace
```

> If you've already upgraded, run the above commands, then manually downgrade to the Trusty packages:

```
sudo -S wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo -S wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/procps/procps_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo -S wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/strace/strace_4.8-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
sudo -S dpkg -i sudo_1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo -S dpkg -i procps_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo -S dpkg -i strace_4.8-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

More info here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/482

Comment: FYI, the `sudo` download location is currently tossing a 404.

Comment: In the sudo package URL, change 1ubuntu1.1_ to 1ubuntu1_ to fix the 404.

Comment: I got an error about libprocps3 when installing procps. This fixed that:

```sudo -S wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/procps/libprocps3_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb;
 sudo -S dpkg -i libprocps3_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb```

Answer (score 14):

WSL uses the lxrun executable for management from Windows:

`lxrun -h`

```
Usage:
    /install - Installs the subsystem
        Optional arguments:
            /y - Do not prompt user to accept
    /uninstall - Uninstalls the subsystem
        Optional arguments:
            /full - Perform a full uninstall
            /y - Do not prompt user to accept
    /setdefaultuser - Configures the subsystem user that bash will be launched as. If the user does not exist it will be created.
        Optional arguments:
            username - Supply the username
            /y - If username is supplied, do not prompt to create a password
    /update - Updates the subsystem's package index
```

Given that, you can use `lxrun /setdefaultuser root`. Just thought I'd point out this side of it since it was required when I ran into the same issue as you after trying to upgrade to Xenial. I can confirm that running [this command](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/482#issuecomment-234695431), then the wget / dpkg commands my issues were resolved.

The commands I used:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/procps/procps_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/strace/strace_4.8-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
dpkg -i sudo_1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
dpkg -i procps_3.3.9-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i strace_4.8-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Finally, you might need to run `sudo apt-get install -f` in case you get `The following packages have unmet dependencies [xxx] but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: This worked great. I ran into this problem after doing a `do-release-upgrade`. Once I ran `lxrun /setdefaultuser root` I could then open a bash shell and run `visudo` to give my user account back sudo privileges.  After that I went back to powershell and ran `lxrun /setdefaultuser <user>` and am now back to the setup I had before the `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: @Jake Can you explain how did you give sudo privileges to your user account? I did `my_user      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: This actually works better if you do it in reverse order after the wget, you don't even have to change the default user from lxrun.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the error by moving /etc/hosts to /etc/hosts.bu. After closing the shell en opening again, /etc/hosts is recreated and your computer name is added. The error is gone (for me.)